# How do the rules for men travelling alone and women travelling alone differ?

Tags: women, men, travelling

Throughout Islam, there is a lot of attention on women travelling alone, with attitudes varying significantly.  Indeed, there's several questions on this site relating to women travelling alone:

- [Can a Muslim woman study abroad without a mahram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8698/17163)
- [Why are women not allowed to go out alone even in today's society?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31010/17163)
- [How do unmarried women with no mahram go on a pilgrimage to Mecca?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33135/17163)
- [Which mainstream Shia scholars say it's permissible for a woman to travel alone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36150/17163)

However, there seems to be minimal attention given to men travelling alone, so I'm curious about this imbalance.

**Question**: How do the rules for men travelling alone and women travelling alone differ?

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/105280) says that the Prophet "forbade [travelling alone] in several ahaadeeth" without making reference to one's gender (although there is nuance to their post).  I also found this post:

> In times of insecurity and war, in long journeys, the Prophet, pbuh, ordained that a woman should travel with her husband or a male relative. This was meant to help the woman and to provide security, not to put the woman under the control of her husband... -- [Kaukab Siddique](http://www.newtrendmag.org/ntma1614.htm), New Trend Mag, 2009.

I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: The main reason for this "No attention" for males is that they are supposed to be stronger and able to defend themselves. However there is a kind of recommendation to travel as a group and to declare a "leader" (Amir) of the group, which seems to have a basis in sunnah! The rest of your question seem to require Ijtihad!

Answer (score -1):

In Islamic tradition, there are certain guidelines and recommendations for both men and women when traveling alone, which take into consideration their safety and well-being. Here are some of the differences between the rules for men and women traveling alone in Islam:

Women are advised to travel with a male mahram (a close male relative, such as a father, brother, or husband) for their protection and safety. Men are not required to travel with a mahram but it is recommended for them to travel with a group of other men for safety.

Women are advised to dress modestly and cover their bodies when traveling to avoid unwanted attention and to maintain their dignity. Men are also advised to dress modestly and avoid clothing that draws attention.

Women are advised to be careful and cautious when traveling alone, especially at night or in unfamiliar places. Men are also advised to be cautious when traveling alone, but they are generally considered to be less vulnerable to harassment or violence.

Women are advised to avoid traveling long distances alone, especially by foot or public transportation, as this can be dangerous. Men are also advised to avoid traveling long distances alone if possible.

Women are advised to inform their family or friends of their travel plans and keep them updated on their whereabouts. Men are also advised to inform someone of their travel plans and keep in touch during their trip.

It is important to note that these guidelines are meant to ensure the safety and well-being of both men and women when traveling alone, and they are not intended to restrict their freedom or limit their opportunities. Muslims are encouraged to exercise good judgment and common sense when traveling and to seek guidance from Islamic scholars or trusted advisors if needed.